# Firestore is deleting the last document not the one I selected

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to impelement a delete function in Firestore database and the problem is that when I click delete, it deletes the last document created, not the one that I want to delete.
This is how I get the data from the database:

```
db.collection("flights").get().then((snapshot) =>{ 
   snapshot.docs.forEach(doc => {
   var data = doc.data();
   var docID = doc.id;
```

And this is how I am trying to delete it:

```
function deleteFlight(docID){
   firebase.firestore()
  .collection("flights")
  .doc(docID)
  .delete()
  .then(() => console.log("Document deleted")) // Document deleted
  .catch((error) => console.error("Error deleting document", error));
}
```

I want to specify that after I create a new document, the website is refreshed, so I think it loses somehow the document id.

Comment: Can you share a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? There's no way to figure out where that `docID` is coming from.

Comment: From which part of your code are you calling deleteFlight() function?

Comment: The docID is assigned to doc.id, wich is coming from the database and I am calling deleteFlight() function from a HTML button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comment section you have specified that you are calling the `deleteFlight()` function from a html button. As you are using `forEach()` loop after getting the collection of documents and within that populating `docID`, by the time the html button is clicked the `forEach()` loop would have been completed and then `docID` will have the document id of the document which comes last in ascending order because by default the documents are sorted in ascending order of document id as mentioned in [this document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data#order_and_limit_data). In your case I suspect the document id for the recently added document comes last when sorted in ascending order. This is the reason the recently added document is getting deleted.

I am not sure of your use case. But I would suggest you to declare a variable outside of the `db.collection()` method and implement some logic according to your use case to populate it with the document id which you want to delete. Then use that variable in the `deleteFlight()` function.